# Trouble using angular ui's layout directive

Tags: jquery-ui, layout, angular-ui

I was trying Angular UI's ui.layout directive that allows to split the view .

```
https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-layout/
```

I was using this as a replacement for JQUERY UI layout plugin . So I wanted the same behaviour in angular . I am having just two div's suppose east and west and I wanted to split the layout into 1:3 ratio  . In angular it splits in 1:1 ratio . I am able to change it using the splitbar but when I refresh the page it goes back to the initial stage . This was not the case in Jquery UI Layout .Once I drag the splitbar and refresh , the layout remains the same .

Please Help !!

Comment: I am guessing, [this feature request](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout/issues/13) on their Github issue tracker is you?

Comment: Do you have a solution for that . ??

Comment: Saving UI layout changes in local cache is a missing feature. See the link in my previous comment (official feature request by OP).

Comment: Oh . God , why dint i think of that . Thank you @Domi